# Supress RegDll Error Messages in NSIS

Tags: dll, nsis

I am doing an installer and I have an issue when it gets uninstalled that Windows will throw an error (even if run using `regsrv32 /u` so essentially I want to add the `/s` flag to the `RegDll "$SYSDIR\foo32.dll"` in the NSIS script.

I also assume that `$SysDir` will be `windows\syswow64` on 64-bit systems, and `system32` on 32-bit?  it is a 32-bit driver that exists in the system path.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you mean driver? Drivers are not usually installed by regsrv32/RegDll and on 64-bit systems all drivers must be 64-bit!

Comment: It is a video codec that is being enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused because you are talking about `RegDLL` and regsrv32.exe and they are different things! `RegDLL` can never use a /s switch because the functions it calls do not have a silent parameter.

RegDLL and UnRegDLL are NSIS instructions and internally they call `LoadLibrary`+`GetProcAddress` for DllRegisterServer and DllUnregisterServer respectively and never uses regsrv32.exe. They never display any message dialogs but they do print some text to the log on the instfiles page and you can control this with `SetDetailsPrint`. The registration functions in your libraries might display a messagebox but there is nothing NSIS can do about that.

NSIS also ships with a header file called [Library.nsh](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/AppendixB.html#library_intro) and it contains more advanced control over how things are registered and it might call out to "$SYSDIR\regsvr32.exe" for 64-bit libraries but it always uses the /s switch. When using Library.nsh you must set the correct defines if you are also installing 64-bit libraries!

If you are always installing just a 32-bit library it might look something like this:

```
!include Library.nsh
Section Uninstall
!insertmacro UnInstallLib REGDLL NOTSHARED REBOOT_NOTPROTECTED "$InstDir\whatever.dll"
SectionEnd
```

If you have 32 and 64-bit libraries it might look something like this:

```
!include Library.nsh
!include x64.nsh
Section Uninstall
!insertmacro UnInstallLib REGDLL NOTSHARED REBOOT_NOTPROTECTED "$InstDir\whatever-32.dll"

${If} ${RunningX64}
  !define LIBRARY_X64
  !insertmacro UnInstallLib REGDLL NOTSHARED REBOOT_NOTPROTECTED "$InstDir\whatever-64.dll"
  !undef LIBRARY_X64
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Yes I was using it for comparison purposes, I know they're different! :-)  Yes, the library is always 32-bit, even on 64-bit systems.  Just wanted to point out that on command line `regsvr32 /u` and `UnRegDll` have the same "error" which isn't really an error as it still unregisters, but I don't want the error to occur when running `unregdll`.

Comment: regsvr32 /u displays the error but regsvr32 /s /u does not? It would be helpful if you could explain what this error is and what it looks like. Is it a messagebox (a new popup dialog)? If UnRegDll displays a messagebox then there is nothing NSIS can do about it because UnRegDll only prints to the log on the instfiles page and anything else comes from the component you are unregistering.

Comment: regsvr32 from admin command prompt succeeds, just as regdll does without incident.  regsvr32 /u provides an error dialogue box, just as unregdll does (the same exact one to be precise).  regsrv32 /u /s is successfull and does not display the error dialogue.  i like to do something similar for unregdll so it displays no feedback whatsoever.  or is there a shell32.dll function where i can do so?

Comment: I don't know how many more times I can say it, UnRegDll does not display a messagebox, it only adds to the log on the InstFiles page but you can disable that with "SetDetailsPrint none". The /s regsrv32 switch just turns off the messagebox inside regsrv32. If you absolutely want to use /u /s you can just do ExecWait '"$sysdir\regsvr32.exe" /u /s "$instdir\mycomponent.dll"'

Comment: Ok.  Sorry Anders.  I did not know what was triggering and not know the behaviour of unregdll.  All I witness was the lack of feedback when using dos prompt which is expected behaviour but it is what it is.